# JTable combined with innerJoin statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have 2 database tables and I want to join them into a JTable. At first, I created 2 JTables for the 2 database tables but I wanted to give it a try and put them into 1 JTable,combining them. My 1st db table "consoles" consists of 3 columns (id, name and cost) and my 2nd table "hardware" consists of 4 columns(id,CPU,Memory and HDD).

My issue is in the loop. When I write

```
while (rs.next()) {
    a = rs.getString(1);
    b = rs.getString(2);
    c = rs.getString(3);
    while (rss.next()) {
        aa = rss.getString(2);
        bb = rss.getString(3);
        cc = rss.getString(4);
    }
    model.addRow(new Object[] { a, b, c, aa, bb, cc });
}
```

i get the same values fot the aa,bb,cc which is the CPU,Memory and HDD of the 2nd table.

When i write

```
while (rs.next()) {
    a = rs.getString(1);
    b = rs.getString(2);
    c = rs.getString(3);
    while (rss.next()) {
        aa = rss.getString(2);
        bb = rss.getString(3);
        cc = rss.getString(4);
        model.addRow(new Object[] { a, b, c, aa, bb, cc });
    }
}
```

i get the same values for a,b,c which are the id,the name and the cost of the 1st table

Any ideas?

Here is my full code:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel();
table = new JTable(model);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
model.fireTableDataChanged();
model.addColumn("id");
model.addColumn("name");
model.addColumn("cost");
model.addColumn("CPU");
model.addColumn("Memory");
model.addColumn("HDD");

try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmtt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consoles INNER JOIN hardware ON consoles.id=hardware.id");
    rss = stmtt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM hardware");
    while (rs.next()) {
        // a = id, b = name, c = cost
        a = rs.getString(1);
        b = rs.getString(2);
        c = rs.getString(3);
        while (rss.next()) {
            // rss.getString(1) is the id,dont need that
            // aa = CPU, bb = Memory, cc = HDD
            aa = rss.getString(2);
            bb = rss.getString(3);
            cc = rss.getString(4);
            model.addRow(new Object[] { a, b, c, aa, bb, cc });
        }

    }

    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
    table.setBounds(218, 59, 529, 360);
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    model.fireTableDataChanged();

    conn.close();
    stmt.close();
    stmtt.close();
    rs.close();
    rss.close();

}
catch (SQLException case1) {
    case1.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception case2) {
    case2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 1. every code lines wrapped into two model.fireTableDataChanged(); haven't something with JDBC, should be before or after is JDBC executed, 2. don't to create, set, modify GUI inside try - catch -finally, 3. Connection & Statement should be close() in finally

Comment: model.fireTableDataChanged();??? for DefaultTableModel talking about EDT issue, more in Oracle tutotial Concurency in Swing - EventDispatchThread

Comment: why are you having 2 queries since you can join 2 table in one query and get all the columns that you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result set should return all the fields you need per result. You should not have to use two queries. Select individual fields like below

```
select c.field1, c.field2, h.field1 ... 
from consolas c inner join hardware h 
on c.someField = h.someField
```

I've never seen anyone do what you're trying to do. Maybe you should do over some sql tutorials.

What happens when you do both, is not what you are expecting. Your first query will already return all the fields. That's the point of a join. You may not be getting all the results from the rs.getXxx() as you may not be expecting them.

You could do a simple test using ResultSetMetaData class to get the column count, and print out all the values. Something like

```
ResultSet rs = ...
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
```

Then loop through the result set using the column count as the max loop iteration. For example

```
while(rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        System.out.print(rs.getObject(i) + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here's a generic common way to accomplish what you're trying to do

```
ResultSet rs = ...
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

String[] cols = new String[columnCount];
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
    col[i - 1] = md.getColumnName(i);
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);

while(rs.next()) {
    Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
    }
    model.addRow(row);
}

table.setModel(model);
```

Comment: and what variables would I use for the xxx.getString() method inside the loop since we are talking about 2 tables?

Comment: Do you mean if you use the resultsetmetadata column count to loop?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. See the bottom part of my answer (I just updated). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah im not familiar with that so my questions sound childish

Comment: I don't know why you are mentioning two tables. Once you do the join, the results should contain fields from both tables, all in one result row. Print it out like in post to see

Comment: Ok now I get it.....but because I may encounter issues adding the results into a JTable instead of just printing them, i may comment again about how doing that....thanks a lot btw!

Comment: FYI You don't _have_ to use the  for loop for your code. I was just merely show you how you can see all the values returned. For your code, once you know all the values and columns returned just have a bunch of `rs.getXxx()` in the the while loop.

Comment: Wait now I'm confused...since using the getObject() method returns me all of the tables' values(both tables as I see), wouldn't using rs.getxxx method be a duplicate method......I feel like they do the same things.

Comment: If you want to use the loop, then create an new `Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];` before the loop. Then in the loop, just set the index `row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);` Then add the row after the loop. What you are doing is adding a row for _each_ value of each row

Comment: FYI, when I say `getXxx` I just mean it could be `getInt()`, `getString()`, `getDouble()`, or whatever, if you already know what types they are to return. This is just is there are values other than Strings. But is there are values other than Strings, you're going to need an `Object[]` anyway, so just using the for loop is fine

Comment: And one more thing, I noticed in your loop, you're starting at 0. Remember the resultset indices start at 1 not 0. So you're trying to access a bad index

Comment: Its a shame that becuase of my low rep(recently joined) i cannot transfer it into a chat.. Anywat the row[i-1] = rs.getxxx(i); statement is not working because of this error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object". Is casting an option?

Comment: See my **UPDATE** It's generic code example of how to accomplish this

Comment: Solved. Will post the answer later with some minor adjustments.
Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consoles INNER JOIN hardware ON consoles.id=hardware.id");
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
            String[] cols = new String[columnCount];
            for (i=1;i<= columnCount;i++)
            {
                cols[i-1] = md.getColumnName(i);
                // you had missed an "s" here, nothing important
            }

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols,0);

            while (rs.next())
             {
                Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
                  for (i = 1 ; i <= columnCount ; i++)
                  {
                    row[i-1] = rs.getObject(i);
                  }
                  model.addRow(row);
              }
            table = new JTable(model);// table.setModel(model) created error
            model.fireTableDataChanged();
```